# linux system slowdown debugging, high sys usage

Tags: linux, high-load, btrfs, linuxmint

I have a remote linux system that became super slow yesterday. Since the remote luks unlocking I've setup doesn't seem to work reliable and I won't be able to physically access the machine within the next 10 days I'm trying to debug this instead of rebooting.

The system status tools I'm used to are `htop` and `dstat` and since I had `dstat` running in an ssh session I can see that since yesterday 2021-09-09 08:51:42 one cpu core is always fully used by "sys" - which I guess means the kernel?

I can't see any culprit process or thread in `htop`.

I've stopped all user services and unmounted everything non essential which made the system respond a bit better again but still not nearly as fast as it should (got an Intel i7 CPU with an SSD).

I've found https://tanelpoder.com/posts/high-system-load-low-cpu-utilization-on-linux/ and installed the referenced https://0x.tools/ to get this result for `psn -G syscall,wchan`:

```
=== Active Threads ========================================================================================

 samples | avg_threads | comm              | state                  | syscall   | wchan                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     100 |        1.00 | (btrfs-cleaner)   | Running (ON CPU)       | [running] | 0                        
     100 |        1.00 | (dpkg)            | Disk (Uninterruptible) | fsync     | btrfs_commit_transaction 
     100 |        1.00 | (systemd-journal) | Disk (Uninterruptible) | ftruncate | wait_current_trans       
       1 |        0.01 | (sshd)            | Running (ON CPU)       | [running] | 0                        
       1 |        0.01 | (thermald)        | Disk (Uninterruptible) | [running] | ec_guard                 
       1 |        0.01 | (thermald)        | Running (ON CPU)       | [running] | 0
```

The `dpkg` process can be explained by me trying to run `apt upgrade` which run's around at a 1/1000th of the speed you'd normally expect (just a feeling, didn't measure it).

Maybe there's a problem with my btrfs root file system...? I can't find the `btrfs-cleaner` in `htop`, I guess I'm gonna research some more on what that is..

I did run a `btrfs scrub` last night which completed super fast and didn't find any problems:

```
# btrfs scrub status /
UUID:             2f38e0ad-7f16-4a36-8096-b7981d47b4ff
Scrub started:    Thu Sep  9 23:59:00 2021
Status:           finished
Duration:         0:00:24
Total to scrub:   53.09GiB
Rate:             1.78GiB/s
Error summary:    no errors found
```

But when I used nano to modify a config file on the root partition loading and saving it was super slow just now.

I just stumbled upon this: https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/fmucrq/btrfs_snapshots_make_entire_system_lag_cpu_usage/ which has a comment that sounds similar to my problem:

> every time on boot and after a snapshot btrfs-transacti and btrfs-cleaner would use up a core completely causing immense lag

only that this says it just lasts a few minutes on boot and snapshot creation, but I've disabled my `btrbk` backup setup on this system a few days ago when one of the attached disks started to show problems.

I'm not sure if my btrfs root filesystem was using `qgroups`, but I just ran `btrfs quota disable /` which took around 10 seconds and didn't give any feedback.

Anybody got any other hint's for me how to debug / solve this problem?

Comment: Ah, I think I found why quotas where enabled, I've used btrfs-du and btdu to see what subvolumes use how much space and a comment over there says btrfs-du enables quoates automatically: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190405/how-does-enabling-btrfs-quotas-impact-the-system says btrfs-du enables it automatically. `btdu` seems to be the better alternative to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem where those btrfs quotas.
Running

```
btrfs quota disable /
```

made the system usable again :)